# Something similar: Substring but for integer - Progress4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hi Can someone help me with a question, please?

I have an integer in a cell in a spreadsheet and I only want to grab the first 6 digits out of the 7 in the cell from my input/read data set. How do I do that?

For a string, I would do something like:

...after def all relevant var and source documents:

variablexyz = substring(data[1]1,6) - right?

How do I do the same thing for an integer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest math and not string manipulation in that case.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i     AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iData AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO INITIAL "1234567".

i = ROUND (iData / 10 - .5 , 0) . 

MESSAGE i
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: Legend. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you want to be using ROUND() for that. TRUNCATE() is simpler and more appropriate.  I.e.  truncate( iData / 10, 0 ).